# Huge size of the system32/config folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, disk-space

My 128 GB SSD disk is running out of space, so I am looking for the multiple ways to save the disk space:

- Disabled the hibernation,
- Cleaned up the Windows backup-data,
- Moved the swapfile to other disk

I've downloaded the TreeSize Free app, and it has detected that the C:/Windows/System32/config folder is eating **68 192,0 MB**(!) (contains 191525 files) which is obviously out of the standard behaviour.

Is that a known issue? How can I fix the config folder size?

I am using Windows 8.

Comment: I personally would not touch this folder if you want a system that actually boots.  I would run the `Disk Clean-up` tool.  You can also disable the creation of `System Restore` points.

Comment: @Ramhound I already did, like hundreds of times... Including the `chkdsk /r` and defragmentation. I doubt those files are so important to eat the half of my disk space.

Comment: You run a defragmentation routine on a SSD!!!  Why would you do that?  SSD storage is not only suppose to be fragmented it also not relevant.

Comment: [Worth](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/windows-8-pro-cwindowssystem32-keeps-growing/f5606bf5-df3f-4ed8-bfb5-939cc903a4dc?page=3) a read if you have `Nvidia` hardware installed

Comment: @Ramhound Not really on my SSD - Windows is automatically skipping the SSD defragmentation. Yeah, I have Nvidia hardware drivers installed.

Comment: Are we talking about `Windows 8` or `Windows 8.1`.  Well the support article that was linked below seems to confirm your running `Windows 8` and not `Windows 8.1` you might consider upgrading to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some postings over on the Microsoft forums, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2795944/EN-US should have resolved that bug and cleaned up the excess files... can you verify that you have that update or something that supersedes it?

Comment: Thanks. I had the Windows Updates disabled for about 8 months... Didnt even noticed. I will install the update and will let you know about any progress!

Comment: So I have just installed the KB2795944 update and nothing has changed. Unfortunately.

Comment: Nvm , it actually fixed my problem! Having 66,6 GB of the free space! `:D` Thank you so much.